How to display an image in HTML via a JSON file using Javascript
I have a question about using a JSON file.
I almost have what I want, except the images won't show on my page. Instead paths to the images are printed out:

The JSON file is like a little database just for the thumbnails of the blog posts, so I don't have to hard code them. On the print screen, I have already a little bit of what I want. I am not worried about the styling, I will take care of that after I understand this problem.
Here is the JSON file:
[
  {
    "postid": "4",
    "title": "More coming soon",
    "text": "Soon I will add more recipes, this is just the start of a blog full of content! Come back regulary",
    "img": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/735509975649378305/B81JwLT7.jpg",
    "url": "#"
  },
  {
    "postid": "3",
    "title": "Pizza",
    "text": "The Italian classic, so many different styles of it. Try this recipe at home, for a crusty tastfull pizza!",
    "img": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/735509975649378305/B81JwLT7.jpg",
    "url": "#"
  },
  {
    "postid": "2",
    "title": "Madeleines",
    "text": "French classic scallop shape little cakes, perfect with a cup of coffee. You can make them easy at home!",
    "img": "../assets/images/recipes/Madeleines.png",
    "url": "#"
  },
  {
    "postid": "1",
    "title": "Moelleux",
    "text": "A special one for the chocolate lovers! The best chocolate dessert is very easy to make, give it a try...",
    "img": "../assets/images/recipes/Moelleux.png",
    "url": "#"
  }
]

Here is the HTML:
  <!--  Jason test  -->
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <label for="search">Search Users</label>
    <input type="search" id="search" data-search>
  </div>
  <div class="user-cards" data-post-cards-container></div>
  <template data-post-template>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="header" data-header></div>
      <div class="body" data-body></div>
      <div class="photo" data-photo></div>
    </div>
  </template>
  <!--  End Jason test  -->

Here is the Javascript:
const postCardTemplate = document.querySelector("[data-post-template]")
const postCardContainer = document.querySelector("[data-post-cards-container]")
const searchInput = document.querySelector("[data-search]")

let posts = []

searchInput.addEventListener("input", e => {
  const value = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
  posts.forEach(post => {
    const isVisible =
      post.title.toLowerCase().includes(value)
    post.element.classList.toggle("hide", !isVisible)
  })
})

fetch("../jsn/posts-main.json")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    posts = data.map(post => {
      const card = postCardTemplate.content.cloneNode(true).children[0]
      const header = card.querySelector("[data-header]")
      const body = card.querySelector("[data-body]")
      const img = card.querySelector("[data-photo]")
      header.textContent = post.title
      body.textContent = post.text
      img.textContent = post.img
      postCardContainer.append(card)
      return { title: post.title, element: card }
    })
})


The issue is because you're just appending the URL to the image as text within the parent div.
To fix the problem you need to create an img element and set the information from the fetch request as the src of that img.
Here's a simplified example:


// mock AJAX data:
const data = [{postid:"4",title:"More coming soon",text:"Soon I will add more recipes, this is just the start of a blog full of content! Come back regulary",img:"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/735509975649378305/B81JwLT7.jpg",url:"#"},{postid:"3",title:"Pizza",text:"The Italian classic, so many different styles of it. Try this recipe at home, for a crusty tastfull pizza!",img:"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/735509975649378305/B81JwLT7.jpg",url:"#"},{postid:"2",title:"Madeleines",text:"French classic scallop shape little cakes, perfect with a cup of coffee. You can make them easy at home!",img:"../assets/images/recipes/Madeleines.png",url:"#"},{postid:"1",title:"Moelleux",text:"A special one for the chocolate lovers! The best chocolate dessert is very easy to make, give it a try...",img:"../assets/images/recipes/Moelleux.png",url:"#"}];


const postCardTemplate = document.querySelector("[data-post-template]")
const postCardContainer = document.querySelector("[data-post-cards-container]")

// within fetch handler
let posts = []

posts = data.map(post => {
  const card = postCardTemplate.content.cloneNode(true).children[0]
  const header = card.querySelector("[data-header]")
  const body = card.querySelector("[data-body]")
  const img = card.querySelector("[data-photo]")
  
  header.textContent = post.title
  body.textContent = post.text
  
  const imgContent = document.createElement('img');
  imgContent.src = post.img;
  img.appendChild(imgContent);
  
  postCardContainer.append(card)
  return {
    title: post.title,
    element: card
  }
})
<div class="search-wrapper">
  <label for="search">Search Users</label>
  <input type="search" id="search" data-search>
</div>
<div class="user-cards" data-post-cards-container></div>
<template data-post-template>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="header" data-header></div>
      <div class="body" data-body></div>
      <div class="photo" data-photo></div>
    </div>
  </template>



